# VBA Range.Name broken?

Tags: excel, vba

So I am running a VBA application that finds associated cells to a value, creates a range out of them, then fills a data validation drop down list by associating that range with a name.

This was allowing me to create a dynamically populated dropdown list population by doing the following:

1. Change event causes code to fire
2. This then scans another sheet for a value entered by user
3. When this value is found, a cell on that row is added to a range object
4. This range object gets its Range.Name property assigned using info from the cell the drop down list is in.
5. This worked in an older version of excel

What used to happen-> Name: LotnumbersF3 == created name Validation list Source = nothing -run code -build range -assign range.name = LotnumbersF3 -Drop Down list populates with range info

What happens now-> range.Name = Nothing run code range.Name = "LotnumbersF3" //my code does this //Check value of name range.Name = "=sheet!$D$7,sheet!$D$21......

I need the name to equal a specific value, why has this changed?

Edit:

So here is the code that associates to a name already created on the sheet:

```
ListNamePostFix = Replace(Target.Offset(0, 1).AddressLocal, "$", "")
```

So now I run a matching alg that utilizes up to three potential unique keys to describe different drop down list associations. Some of the lists depend on the value selected in other dropdown lists:

```
For Each RngCell In WorkingRng
    If ThreeArgs Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -7).Value = RngCell.Value _
        And Target.Offset(0, -2).Value = RngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value _
        And Target.Value = RngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            If Not NamedRng Is Nothing Then
                Set NamedRng = Union(NamedRng, ASP.Cells(Index, Column))
            Else
                Set NamedRng = ASP.Cells(Index, Column)
            End If
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    ElseIf TwoArgs Then
        If Target.Offset(0, -5).Value = RngCell.Value And Target.Value = RngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value Then
            If Not NamedRng Is Nothing Then
                Set NamedRng = Union(NamedRng, ASP.Cells(Index, Column))
            Else
                Set NamedRng = ASP.Cells(Index, Column)
            End If
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    Else
        If RngCell.Value = Target.Value Then
            If Not NamedRng Is Nothing Then
                Set NamedRng = Union(NamedRng, ASP.Cells(Index, Column))
            Else
            'innitializes the range object with first match.
                Set NamedRng = ASP.Cells(Index, Column)
            End If
        End If
        Index = Index + 1
    End If
Next
```

This function is called before this:

```
 If Not NamedRng Is Nothing Then
        ListName = ListName & ListNamePostFix
        NamedRng.Name = "LOTNUMBERS"
    Else
        Set NamedRng = Cells(1, 1)
        ListName = "LOTNUMBERS" & ListNamePostFix
        NamedRng.Name = ListName
    End If
```

And in an older version, not sure which one, of excel this works fine. But now according to the wonderful answer provided we see that the Name object no longer associates with a string, but some unholy amalgamation of the range elements thhat have been added to the working range. WHY!!!!!????

Comment: dont know how to edit after a post, but sorry for the broken code format, and "LOTNUMBERS" should be replaced by ListName

Comment: At the bottom there should be an edit post button. Also consider posting up the entire code (where relevant) as this would generate more viewers to possibly answer.

Comment: `Range.Name` returns a `Name` object, not a string. The string you're getting is the `Name` object's default property ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.name)), which has an oddly side-effecting `Property Let` implementation that makes `NamedRng.Name = "LOTNUMBERS"` be legal, but that code doesn't do what it looks like it's doing - there's a lot of implicit stuff going on under the hood there. Now I'd post an answer, but I've no idea what the "what used to happen"/"what happens now" sequences mean. Feel free to [edit] to clarify.